# How to use macports to configure my GDB version on Mac Mountain Lion

Tags: gdb, macports, configure

I have just used macports to install on my Mac the newest gdb by using `sudo port install gdb`. The problem is when I type `gdb` in the command line it still shows the old version. How can I switch to the new one I just installed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Type :

```
port contents gdb
```

It gives you where is located the port

```
 /opt/local/bin/ggdb
  /opt/local/include/ansidecl.h
  /opt/local/include/bfd.h
  /opt/local/include/bfdlink.h
  /opt/local/include/dis-asm.h
  /opt/local/include/gdb/jit-reader.h
  /opt/local/include/symcat.h
  /opt/local/lib/libbfd.a
  /opt/local/lib/libbfd.la
  /opt/local/lib/libopcodes.a
  /opt/local/lib/libopcodes.la
  ...
```

As you can see below it is named ggdb, not gdb when you have installed it with MacPorts

```
ggdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb)
```